# load angularjs web from local file system

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an **angularjs web** page which **must be loaded from the local file system**.

Why not a server:
**I don't want to use a local server**, since this would complicate distributing the web to my work mates. **It's not possible to host it in a server** (because we don't have it, company security won't allow to use a public server, and we sometimes have to work offline).

[image]

I already have the web programmed using plain html, javascript and jquery. When there's a new version,

- I pack it in a .zip file,
- send it to my mates,
- they unzip it
- double click on the file index.html to open on chrome or similar,
- and they are ready to start working with the page.

As the project gets bigger and bigger, we need to port it to angular.
While developing, I can use the build-in angularjs server `> ng serve`.
However, after I build it, **it doesn't load correctly from filesystem using index.html from local filesystem**.

[image]

I can't ask my work mates to install the node and angularjs to run the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing script with type=module from local folder causes a CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873280/importing-script-with-type-module-from-local-folder-causes-a-cors-issue)  And https://stackoverflow.com/q/50197495/328193, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/74968721/328193, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69065352/328193, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/52139811/328193, etc.

Comment: Second link gives an important clue about the CORS: In the dist/index.html file I remove the keyword ```type="module"```. This DO actually works. However, is there a way to do this changes automatically everytime I compile?

I also have to  change ```<base href="/">``` with ```<base href="./">``` in the source index.html. But this change is persistent, I don't have to do it over an over again after each built.

Comment: Other links mostly suggest using a local server, which is what I want to avoid. On the other hand, this links provide good advise in case a finally have to use a local server

Comment: Building that case is probably going to be the more productive route in the long run.  If your employer wants to rely on complex modern web applications then "without a web server" is a strange and misguided requirement.  Other options include continuing to rely on older/simpler tools (e.g. the jQuery app you mentioned in the question), deploying it with build/run instructions for local web servers, or not using a web application at all and choosing some other tool/technology.  Basically, *using* the tools is going to be more productive than *fighting* the tools.

Comment: I'll give a try to https://www.electronjs.org/. It creates a desktop app out of the angularjs web. However, the first version of the web with angular, after build, is **260 kB**, while the compiled electron app is **230 MB**.